# compact convex sets

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $A\in R^{n\times n}$ and $B\in R^{m\times m}$ are symmetric positive definite matrices. Is the following set convex and compact?

$\mathcal{S}^{+}=\left\{C\in R^{n\times m}\Big|\begin{bmatrix}A&C\\C^T&B\end{bmatrix}>0\right\}$

How about the following set:

$\mathcal{S}=\left\{C\in R^{n\times m}\Big|\begin{bmatrix}A&C\\C^T&B\end{bmatrix}\geq 0\right\}$

Is $\mathcal{S}$ homeomorphic to a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ for an arbitrary norm, where $p=n\times m$.

Comment: what do you mean by pôsitive here

Comment: $Y>0$ here means $Y$ is positive definite. $Y\geq 0$ means $Y$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: then both set are convex

Comment: Proving convexity is straight-forward. How about compactness?

Comment: the first is clearly not compact and for the second just check whether the set is bounded

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: well the first is open and the second is closed can see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Eric Brown, there is another way to prove the boundedness of $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal S^+$.

The original large matrix is symmetric positive (semi-)definite iff
$$\begin{bmatrix}A^{-\frac12} & 0 \\ 0 & B^{-\frac12}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A & C \\ C^T & B\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A^{-\frac12} & 0 \\ 0 & B^{-\frac12}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I & P:=A^{-\frac12}CB^{-\frac12} \\ P^T=B^{-\frac12}CA^{-\frac12} & I\end{bmatrix}$$
is also iff its Schur complement $F:=I-P^TP\succ(\succeq)0$. Diagonalization leads to the spectral norm of $\|P\|<(\le)1$. This is actually a generalization and stronger version of the enry-wise inequality derived in my previous answer $A_{i,i}^{-1}C_{i,j}^2B_{j,j}^{-1}<(\le)1$. As a corollary, the diagonal entries of $F$ should be positive (nonnegative), thus each column 2-norm of $P$ or $\sqrt{\sum_jP_{i,j}^2}<(\le)1$, so is each individual entry $P_{i,j}$ of $P$.

$\mathcal S$ is closed, so it is compact. $\mathcal S^+$ is not closed as  $C$ can reduce the rank of the original large matrix by continuously changing it value, so it is not compact.

Comment: To complete your the answer, in case of $\mathcal{S}$ we can also conclude that the set is compact, right?

Comment: @EricBrown: Yes. The proof regarding compactness is verbatim to the second paragraph in the previous answer. I just copied that to the current answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are bounded. Suppose the opposite is true. Because of the equivalence of norms, we look at the Frobenius norm. As $m$ and $n$ are finite, by the pigeonhole principle, there exists at least one entry, say $(i,j)$, of $C$ the set of the values of which is unbounded.  The $2\times 2$ principle minor $\begin{bmatrix}A_{i,i} & C_{i,j} \\ C_{i,j} & B_{j,j} \end{bmatrix}$ of the original large matrix should be positive (semi-)definite, which stipulates that $C_{i,j}^2\le A_{i,i}B_{j,j}$. We have a contradiction.

$\mathcal S$ is closed, so it is compact. $\mathcal S^+$ is not closed as  $C$ can reduce the rank of the original large matrix by continuously changing it value, so it is not compact.

Comment: Every $C\in\mathcal{S}$ satisfies $C=\sqrt{A}P\sqrt{B}^\top$ where $\|P\|\leq 1$ (P is a contraction matrix). Set of contraction matrices are compact (in the sense defined in the question statement), aren't they?. If that is true, doesn't it mean that $\mathcal{S}$ is compact?

Comment: @EricBrown: Oops, I meant to say they were bounded but somehow led astray by some unknown force :-P and wrote the diametric opposite statement in my haste. So you are right. The previous proof by contradiction was correct and actually proved the boundedness rather than the opposite. I have now corrected the statements but left the proof which was correct intact. Check it out.